API Iteration with powershell
We do have Sentinelone API from which we are trying to fetch applications list total records are more than 2000.
API Uri has 1000 as a limit which gives 1000 entries in Json format.
Json format gives data for pagination and nextCursor.
How to get All the records with powershell.
Following codes givens output of 1000 items in JSON format-
$params=@{
   "Uri"="https://SentineloneURL/web/api/v2.1/application-management/risks?endpointTypes=%22server%22&osTypes=%22windows%22&limit=1000"
   "Method" ="GET"
   "Headers" = @{
      "Content-Type" = 'application/json'
      "Authorization" = 'APIToken KEY'
   }
}$res=Invoke-RestMethod @params

Here $res gives data in json format and in which we can get application names by $res.data with foreach loop.
Cursor we get for next -
@{nextCursor=cursorkey; totalItems=3000}

Have you looked at this?: https://github.com/davidhowell-tx/PS-SentinelOne

Yes saw this already but in this applications fetching  module is not there

Maybe you've already seen this one too, but just in case you haven't: https://github.com/vradchenko/PowerShell-SentinelOne

Thanks  but you are correct i have seen this too - this is very useful but it dont have Get-Applications module hence trying to create code with Invoke-Webrequest where able to fetch 1000 records but need to perform loop with nextcursor value.

Then why don't you post your code ? Maybe we can help you with the pagination

Code would be great, just replace any security info such as token, tenant, etc... with fake info.

Following codes givens output of 1000 items in JSON format-
$params=@{
"Uri"="https://SentineloneURL/web/api/v2.1/application-management/risks?endpointTypes=%22server%22&osTypes=%22windows%22&limit=1000"
"Method" ="GET"
"Headers" = @{
"Content-Type" = 'application/json'
"Authorization" = 'APIToken KEY'
}
}
$res=Invoke-RestMethod @params
Here $res gives data in json format and in which we can get application names by $res.data with foreach loop.

Can you post the code by editing your original question (with code formatting fences) rather than as a comment. Can you please also post the json response you get that contains the pagination token.

I don't have the means to test this, but something very close to this should work:
$Cursor = ''
$CursorUri = ''
$Data = do {
   if ($Cursor) {
      $CursorUri = "&cursor=$Cursor"
   }
   $params = @{
      'Uri'     = "https://SentineloneURL/web/api/v2.1/application-management/risks?endpointTypes=%22server%22&osTypes=%22windows%22&limit=1000$CursorUri"
      'Method'  = 'GET'
      'Headers' = @{
         'Content-Type'  = 'application/json'
         'Authorization' = 'APIToken KEY'
      }
   }
   $res = Invoke-RestMethod @params
   $res.data
} While ($Cursor = $res.pagination.nextCursor)

When done, the variable $Data should contain all applications.

How to get following programitically ?
$Cursor = ''
$CursorUri = ''

@sush007, look at While (...)

@sush007, on first pass $Cursor is '', which means the if () {} statement is skipped.  If $Cursor = $res.pagination.nextCursor has a value, this does 2 things.  It causes the loop to repeat, but also populates $Cursor with a value and when the if statement is called the second time, it creates the value we need in $CursorUri.  $CursorUri is appended to the end of your Uri in the request.

@sush007, with each pass of the while loop, $res.data returns data.  The $Data = do {...} While (...} will capture in $Data all values produced by the while loop.

Thank you so much this helped , $res.data.application got the application list but need to have the hostname on which its installed in same line. how to achieve it ?

Where is the info for hostname?  How do you access it?  $res.hostname?

Thanks , figured out that need to use foreach loop to iterate required object from the same. Thanks a lot to all.

got the required info but need to get them into csv with $data.hostnames and $data.applications in column , Tried write-output , add-content but it wont give desired output.

@sush007, was afk.  Probably best to post another question related to getting the desired output.  It's possible something like this $Data | Select-Object -Property hostnames, applications | Export-CSV C:\Temp\File.csv is what you want.  but if not, the you probably need to explain in a new question what code you are using, the output you are getting and the output you want.

ok will check and do the needful
